# ionic 4 - Background Geo-location Issue

Tags: typescript, ionic4

For a while, I have been trying to write a code to get lat long from an App build in Ionic. Like most Users, I used

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation to write the code.

This plugin does not work, I'm looking for the best way with our without using the plugin.

What I already did was finished using the code from ionic 4 native documentation, In December 2018 it worked. I opened my app today after a while. The app crashed, I re-wrote the code. tried different versions of the plugin but to no avail, they do not work.

```
setBackgroundTracking(){
    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
          .then(() => {

            this.backgroundGeolocation.on('location').subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
              console.log(location);

              // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
              // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your operations are successful or not.
              // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
              this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY
            });

          });


The above code is an exact copy paste from the documentation. and the code is buggy.

Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.ts(2339)

If you guys can fix the code or tell me another way to do it, please let me know. I have just been brainstorming would appreciate input/
```

Comment: in were do you called backgroundGeolocation

Answer (score 1):

Seems you failed to copy/paste from documentation:

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .then(() => {

    this.backgroundGeolocation.on('location').subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
      console.log(location);
```

Comment: I have tried the exact code from documentation as well.

its throws 
Argument of type '"location"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BackgroundGeolocationEvents'.ts(2345)

Comment: as you see I edited my code above, it has the same issue as I stated.

Comment: What command do you use to run your code? Like `ionic serve`. If you run it in browser, it is not supported

Comment: even before I can make a build. the IDE displays error that

Argument of type '"location"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BackgroundGeolocationEvents'.ts(2345)

Comment: Maybe some versions doesn't match. Provide your package.json, maybe someone else could help. I never used this package